# Where does Windows' Phone Link program save its data on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, phone, file-location, microsoft-phone-link

I use the [Windows' Photo Link program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_Link) to link to my phone:

[image]

Where does Windows' Phone Link program save its data (SMS, photos, etc.) on Windows 10?

---

In `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, I don't see any pics though, so I wonder whether pics are stored. Same for SMS:

[image]

Maybe only thumbnails are stored in `phone.db`?

Comment: It will either be in its installation directory within WindowsApps or within a directory in AppData.  Have you looked at those locations, if not, which folders have you eliminated?

Comment: Per the duplicate: `C:\Users\<yourUserName>\AppData\Local\Packages` and in there should be a "Microsoft.YourPhone" folder

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, I don't see any pics though, so I wonder whether pics are stored. Same for SMS. 
Maybe only thumbnails are stored in `phone.db`?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ithlC.png

Comment: Check the `LocalCache\Indexed\<GUID>\System\Database` folders. My `photos.db` is quite large so chances are all your data is stored as binary blobs in sqlite databases.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, sorry indeed I meant to write `photos.db`. Mine is only 12MB.